# How to handle strong parameters as a array in Nested Form? Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, nested-forms

The context is as follows, I have entities that can have multiple roles. These roles are manageable by the user.

For example, Entity named "Lipsum" may be "Cashier and Salesperson". So, this is a relation many_to_many.

So I have my 3 models: Entity, type_entity and entity_by_type

```
    class Entity < ActiveRecord::Base
        has_many :entity_by_types
        has_many :type_entities, :through => :entity_by_types
        accepts_nested_attributes_for :entity_by_types
    end

    class EntityByType < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :entity
        belongs_to :type_entity
    end

    class TypeEntity < ActiveRecord::Base
        has_many :entity_by_types
        has_many :entities, :through => :entity_by_types
    end
```

I have an ordinary CRUD for entity types.

Now, in the CRUD of entities, I have a field Select-Option Multiple. In which the user chooses has 1 or more types, the entity that is creating.

Then my Controller Entity is as follows:

```
    class Logistics::EntitiesController < ApplicationController

      def index
       @type_entities = TypeEntity.all
       render layout: false
       # I use this for show All entities by TypeEntity in my view index
      end

      def show
      end

      def new
       @type_entities = TypeEntity.all
       @entity = Entity.new
       render layout: false
     end

     def create
       entity = Entity.new(entity_parameters)
       if entity.save
         flash[:notice] = "Succesfull!."
        redirect_to :action => :index
       else
        flash[:error] = "Error."
        redirect_to :action => :index
       end
     end

     def edit
      @entity = Entity.find(params[:id])
      @type_entities = TypeEntity.all
      @action = 'edit'
      render layout: false
     end

     def update
      entity = Entity.find(params[:id])
      entity.update_attributes(entity_parameters)
      flash[:notice] = "Succesfull."
      redirect_to :action => :index
     end

     def destroy
       @entity = Entity.destroy(params[:id])
       render :json => @entity
     end

      private
      def entity_parameters
        params.require(:entity).permit(:name, :surname, entity_by_types_attributes: [:id, :entity_id, :type_entity_id])
      end
    end
```

And my partial form (for method create and Update) is:

```
= simple_form_for([:namespace, @entity], html: {class: 'form-horizontal' }) do |f|
   = f.input :name, placeholder: "Nombre", input_html: { class: 'form-control' }, label: false
   = f.input :surname, placeholder: "Apellidos", input_html: { class: 'form-control' }, label: false
    %select.select2#type-entity-select{:name => "entity[entity_by_types_attributes][type_entity_id][]", :style => "width:100%;padding: 0;border: none;", :multiple => true}
      - @type_entities.each do |tent|
        %option{value: "#{tent.id}"}
          = tent.name
```

But, when I click in button submit, and "**type_entity_id**" have 1 or more values; in my database only display a 1 record where, entity_id is OK, however **type_entity_id** is NULL.

Moreover only view a 1 record, when should see 1 or more records, depending on the number of types of choice in the form.

The problem here is the way of pass **type_entity_id** in form of array. So, How I can do that?

P.D

The following is how the params go to my controller:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"ASD"1231+Dssr6mRJcXKh9xHDvuVDmVl4jnwIilRBsuE=", "entity"=>{"name"=>"Lorem", "surname"=>"Ipsum", "entity_by_types_attributes"=>{"type_entity_id"=>["1", "4"]}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def entity_parameters
    params.require(:entity).permit(:name, :surname, entity_by_types_attributes: [:id, :entity_id, {:type_entity_id => []}])
end
```

**Edit:**

In your form and in `def entity_parameters` replace `type_entity_id` with `type_entity_ids`

Thus, the parameter will refer to a set (array) not to a single object. These are the generic method syntaxes:

```
Model.associate_id = some integer
Model.associate_ids = an array (for a has_many relation)
```

Comment: I got error 500: `TypeError (no implicit conversion of String into Integer)`. I updated my question with more information.

Comment: Can you add definition for Create or Update please from your controller?

Comment: Sorry, I have problems with the internet. Now this added.

Comment: OK, I change type_entity_id for type_entity_ids and I get the same error: `TypeError (no implicit conversion of String into Integer) app/controllers/entities_controller.rb:17:in `create'`

Comment: try to get rid of [entity_by_types_attributes] and keep only "entity[type_entity_id] in your form. The associations are there so it should work. Also adjust your def entity_parameters